# How to insert line breaks when calling a function in Python

Tags: python

Let say this is the function that I wanted to call:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train,  y_test = train_test_split(X, y, stratify=y, random_state=42)
```

How do I insert a line break for each output before the queal sign? So that,

```
X_train, 
X_test, 
y_train,  
y_test = train_test_split(X, y, stratify=y, random_state=42)
```

The reason why I'm asking this is I have some function that have many output values and it would be easier to read if I can break the output in one line for each one.

Comment: What's stopping you?

Comment: Can you explain in detail and why do you really need line break.

Comment: The line break in the above code for each output when calling a function

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the left side in parentheses. Then spacing doesn't matter:

```
(X_train, 
X_test, 
y_train,  
y_test) = train_test_split(X, y, stratify=y, random_state=42)
```

Comment: Great, glad to help!